# When adding any app there is a firewall on the page, how can I remove it or disable it?

Tags: security, web-application, app, sharepoint-store

I'm new with SharePoint 2013. after install all Apps from the store I faced an issue. there is a firewall popped on the page for app when i open the page.
for example: after the insert the apps " let’s say 4 apps" and i trying to reopen the page. the firewall appear for 4 time. FYI: it’s an internal portal.
Thank you.

Comment: Seems like those 4 apps are trying to access outside content and your firewall is blocking that. It is not a SharePoint thing; it is a setting in your firewall. Contact the App vendor why and what the App is accessing external content.